# how get thumbline Image from Audio file in wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have to develop media player to play audio file and video file both.

but the problem is: i want to display Album image for audio file.

One option i got: is taglib. but in that it provide bitmap image. i want to show image using URI.

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without more details. Please show your relevant XAML and C# code. Or do you simply want to know the code for loading a bitmap in an Image control?

Comment: No actually the requirement is complex between Image File (Image Viewer) and Music file (Media player ) both in Single player. but no problem I done this      using "IValueConvertor". Thanks for your try. :)